# To bypass browser while obtaining Authorization using GoTo APIs

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, sms, implicit-grant

We are looking to send SMS programmatically through a node JS application.
We are able to send SMS successfully through Postman.
We have created a simple node JS application using the following reference: https://developer.goto.com/guides/Authentication/04_HOW_accessTokenNodeJS/

We observed that we can get the code, and then the access token, but we have to go through the browser and enter credentials/ click allow on it to move forward.

We want to bypass this manual interaction, and do everything through the program automatically.
We did not see any documentation around the same on the developer portal.
We checked the Authorization flow documentation for implicit and Authorization Grants (https://developer.goto.com/Authentication/#section/Authorization-Flows ).
We observed that in both flows it says “The authentication server prompts the user to authenticate using their credentials”

Wanted to understand if it was possible to bypass this browser interaction programmatically?
If so, what would be the steps involved.

We want to bypass the below screens:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heard back from GoTo Support: the authorization code flow might not be a good fit for our use case and integration.